# What does & mean in a MENUITEM in a .rc file?

Tags: windows

I am a beginner in windows programming. I have seen a .rc file which looks like this

```
IDR_MAINFRAME MENU PRELOAD DISCARDABLE  
BEGIN 
    POPUP "&File" 
    BEGIN 
        MENUITEM "&New",                        ID_FILE_NEW 
        MENUITEM "&Open...\tCtrl+O",            ID_FILE_OPEN 
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR 
        MENUITEM "P&rint Setup...",             ID_FILE_PRINT_SETUP 
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR 
        MENUITEM "Recent File",                 ID_FILE_MRU_FILE1, GRAYED 
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR 
        MENUITEM "E&xit",                       ID_APP_EXIT 
    END 
END
```

Can someone explain me what does & mean in MENUITEM "&New"
and what does it mean in MENUITEM "E&xit" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

& defines accelerator for the entry - so menu entry corresponding to "&File" can be selected by pressing "F" when menu is active or "Alt+F" for top level choices.

Same applies to dialog resources.

Comment: In the olden days, these letters were underlined in the menus, but these days it's off by default until you press Alt.